# Footer in blog post displays the title two times

Tags: jekyll

My Jekyll site works fine but in the footer of each page my site title is listed twice.

See the site here: http://www.cornellio.net to see the issue.

How can I prevent the title from showing an extra time?

I am running a very clean install as everything is default except for basic info I filled into `_config.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `_includes/footer.html` remove

```
<h2 class="footer-heading">{{ site.title }}</h2>
```

or

```
<li>{{ site.title }}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your _includes/footer.html at line 5 or line 10. Both reference {{ site.title }}. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/site_template/_includes/footer.html#L5-L10